# How to fix - ImportError: DLL load failed, when importing keras

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to install keras with tensorflow backend

I have run `pip install keras` at first, and then `pip install tensorflow`
both commands finished succesfully, now when i'm trying to import Sequential from keras.models I get error

Here is my code

[image: code]

Here is error

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL).

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/keras/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL).


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I don't know why error is in Russian, maybe it is because of my system language, but here is translation

```
Original error:
ImportError: DLL load failed: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL)

Translation:
ImportError: DLL load failed: A crash occurred in the dynamic link library initialization program. (DLL)
```

I am using

[image: versions]

And Python 3.6.0

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Does your CPU support AVX instructions? See the [list of supported processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions?wprov=sfla1). Also, mention whether you have installed Visual Studio C++ Redistributable 2015 Update 3.

Comment: My processor is `Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B980` and as I understood  `pentium` processors do not support `AVX`. No I've don't installed `Visual Studio C++ Redistributable`

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1**

So, according to the information you provided, follow these steps :

1. Install [Visual Studio C++ Redistributable 2015 Update 3](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe).
2. Since your CPU does not support AVX, go to this [repository](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel). It contains TensorFlow builds supporting SSE, which is compatible with Intel Pentium.
3. Follow this path in the repo -> [tensorflow-windows-wheel/1.12.0/py36/CPU/sse2](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.12.0/py36/CPU/sse2)
4. Download the .whl file ( or click [here](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/1.12.0/py36/CPU/sse2/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl) ).
5. Now, we need to install this file. Use,

   `pip install tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
6. If it shows any error, try changing the relative path to an absolute one.
7. TensorFlow is installed successfully.

**Approach 2**

Install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/). It uses a package manager named `conda` which is similar to `pip`.

1. Create a new Conda environment.

   `conda create --name mytfenv`
2. Install TensorFlow ( version=1.10.0 )

   `conda install tensorflow`

One of the methods would work for you. I personally followed both the approachs as my CPU specifications match yours.

Comment: Why I can't just install the 1.10.0 version using pip?

Comment: For installation with pip, you need to install TensorFlow 1.5.0. Because starting from 1.6.0 TensorFlow official pip package support only AVX.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 1.12 comes together with Keras (`tf.keras` : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras). So you have to import tensorflow and keras first, then use the `keras.Sequential` to create the layer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

#for example
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

For more information refer to official tutorial : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

Answer (score 0):

for CPU you can simply install tensorflow by running the following python code in jupyter notebook. i hope you anaconda installed!

> ```
>           pip.main(['install','tensorflow==1.5'])
> ```

a tensorflow of version greater than 1.6 might give you problems but it comes with some useful features

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with Python 3.7, Jypyter Notebook on Windows 10. And do this:

1. Install [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) - **Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019**. With reboot.
2. And do install-guide on [tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) in my Jypyter Notebook:

   - `pip install --upgrade pip`
   - `pip install tensorflow`
3. Then my commands `import tensorflow` or `import keras` work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Anaconda, create virtual env, install Keras and Tensorflow on it and if still getting DLL Import Error in jupyter notebook - 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
Open up the link, Download the x64 .exe file and install it.