# TensorFlow import error: Anaconda_python 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to import `tensorflow` in python 3. I am using `windows-anaconda`. I cannot run the code;

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

It gives me the below error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>   Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: The Solution here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7995

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54615983/10878733) may help.